# adding CSS class to a Smartytag in CMSmadesimple

Tags: css, content-management-system, smarty, cmsmadesimple

Hi I recently started to re-style a page which uses CMSmadesimple. 
I have no experience in using `CMSms` and `Smartytags`.

but there are some `smartytags` on the page which need styling.

for example this tag `{$entry->morelink}`.  I need to be able to add this  `.link`   CSS class to it.

I have tried everything that I have thought of but nothing seems to work. I have also googled around with out a luck.

I hope there is someone out there that have the experience and knows how to add .class to Smarty tag.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked many times in CMS Made Simple [community](https://forum.cmsmadesimple.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=70999) forums.

Try using Smarty [replace](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl) variable modifier, for example:

```
{$entry->morelink|replace:'class="':'class="link '}
```

In case there is no class attribute on given string, you could stick to replacing *id* or even closing `>`.

```
{$entry->morelink|replace:'id=':'class="link" id='}
```

It's messy solution but will work. It's better to change initial object.

Answer (score 1):

There are other approaches to explore. One is using a Smarty tag that doesn't generate the HTML and only provides the value. For example, depending upon the content module, there may be a tag like, "{$entry->moreurl}" which will only provide the URL and not a tag.

Then, you can build your own HTML:

```
<a href="{$entry->moreurl}" title="{$entry->name}" class="link">View More</a>
```

You will need to find out what that module supports by adding this to the template and viewing the available params:
{$entry|print_r}

If your only option is a tag that also generates HTML, then you can also wrap the Smarty tag inside of a div or span element and assign a class name or id to that.

For example,

```
<span class="link">{$entry->morelink}</span>
```

Then your CSS can be written like this:

```
.link a { color: red; }
```